# Create a tensor by calling a function in a loop in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I need to create a tensor by calling some function `fn` over two other tensors and indices in a loop as follows:

```
tensor = [[fn(tensor1, tensor2, i, j) for i in range(3)] for j in range(4)]
```

Not sure how to approach this problem. Use `tf.map_fn` somehow?

Comment: Uncertainty about the function of your `fn`. You can also try `tf.while_loop` besides `tf.map_fn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for your simple case your code will execute as it is.

```
import tensorflow as tf


sess = tf.Session()

a = tf.constant([1,2,3])
b = tf.constant([3,4,5,6])

def fn( tensor1, tensor2, i, j ):
   return tensor1[i] * tensor2[j]

tensor = [[fn(a, b, i, j) for i in range(3)] for j in range(4)]

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
print (sess.run(tensor))
```

> [[3, 6, 9], [4, 8, 12], [5, 10, 15], [6, 12, 18]]